# ExtJs - Getting all components on page

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I'm using ExtJs 4.2.2 with a single page application.
I have lots of workspaces and i want to make sure that i'm destroying all of the components when moving to a different workspace.
i'm using:

```
Ext.ComponentMgr.getCount()
```

but this just returns the number of components.
how can i query the component xtypes in the page?

Comment: try Ext.ComponentQuery.query('component')

Comment: I want the entire list of components on this page. the same as count returns their count i want their xtype or id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will show the entire component list

```
Ext.ComponentMgr.all.map
```